# select query in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a my application in laravel.my sql query is working fine.I'm bit struck with laravel query

```
select a.type from chart_table a left join color_codes b on a.type=b.type_id group by a.type
```

For the above query tried as

```
DB::table('chart_table')
    ->leftjoin('color_codes','color_codes.type_id','=','chart_table.type')
    ->whereIn('chart_table.user_name',$filter_username_details)
    ->orderBy('color_codes.id', 'asc')
    ->groupBy('chart_table.type')
    ->pluck('chart_table.type')
    ->toArray();
```

I'm getting the error as

```
SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR:  column &quot;color_codes.id&quot; must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function<br />
LINE 1: ...le&quot;.&quot;type&quot; group by &quot;chart_table&quot;.&quot;type&quot; order by &quot;color_cod..
```

What I did wrong in my query

Answer (score 2):

for groupBy, you will have to change strict as false. It will not affect on your any SQL / Eloquent query.

[image]

and then try.

```
DB::table('chart_table')
    ->leftjoin('color_codes','color_codes.type_id','=','chart_table.type')
    ->whereIn('chart_table.user_name',$filter_username_details)
    ->orderBy('color_codes.id', 'asc')
    ->groupBy('chart_table.type')
    ->pluck('chart_table.type')
    ->toArray();
```

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

A small change you will need to do in your project `database.php`

```
Go to config/database.php inside connections => mysql => [ 'strict': false ]
```

[image]

And your will query will become something like this

```
DB::table('chart_table as a')
->select('a.type')
->leftJoin('color_codes as b','b.type_id','=','a.type')
->whereIn('a.user_name',$filter_username_details)
->orderBy('b.id', 'asc')
->groupBy('a.type')
->get()
->toArray();
```